# Why some parts of my script is not working?

Tags: javascript

```
/**
   * Prevent users to inspect my website
   */
  //This code is not working! :()
  document.addEventListener(".keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 123) {
      // Prevent F12
      return false;
    } else if (event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 73) {
      // Prevent Ctrl+Shift+I
      return false;
    }
  });

  //This code is working
  document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

I was expecting that the F12 key and ctrl+shift+I key will will not work. I don't want users to use those keys to inspect my website.

Comment: Why have you not added `event.preventDefault()` to the keydown event handler?

Comment: try `keydown` not `.keydown`.

Comment: I think it is the `.` before keydown.  Try just `document.addEventListener("keydown"`

Comment: by the way, `KeyboardEvent.keyCode` is deprecated

Comment: Event handler functions are called from the event queue, the return value of the handlers is not used anywhere. Also, you can't prevent users to open the DevTools, nothing loaded onto page can be hidden, everything is public.

Comment: *I don't want users to use those keys to inspect my website* - even correct code won't stop that

Comment: I tried to remove the [ . ] but still not work.

Comment: Ah I see. So I will stop using it now. Hehe thank you guys. :)

Answer (score 0):

This code works. It would be best if you used `key` instead of `keyCode` since it has been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode#:%7E:text=Deprecated%3A%20This%20feature%20is%20no,be%20kept%20for%20compatibility%20purposes.).

You should also use `preventDefault` inside the selections where you want to prevent the default behavior.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.key == "F12") {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  else if (event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && event.key == "I") {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

If you want to prevent users from inspecting your web page know that there are more shortcuts that enable this such as:

- <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + J</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + C</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl + U</kbd>